# Winforms app crashing (only) on the server

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am running a Winforms app on the server and after running the app for some time, the app is crashing with a messages on the pictures below. It happens only on the server but not locally. How can I solve this problem?

Images:

[image]

[image: ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/invLK)]

Comment: It seems to be crashing from an `ArgumentOutOfRange`. Does your application enumerate files at all? Either way we'll need to see some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical crash scenario, where you can consider the following,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lexli/archive/2009/08/23/when-the-application-program-crashes-on-windows.aspx

If you cannot install VS on that server to debug, you should capture a crash dump from the machine, and then analyze it on another machine using WinDbg + sos.